# How can I force an unused variable to be part of a block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Considering the following code:

```
- (void)downloadObjectUsingURL: (NSURL *)url;
{
    id file = [self createFileForURL: url];
    Finalization objectFinalization = ^() {
        // we don't access url here, but it would be handy to see it in the debugger
        [file close];
    }
    id request = [self buildRequestFromURL: url];
    [object download: request
              toFile: file
        finalization: objectFinalization];
}
```

What is the easiest way to force `url` to be copied as part of `objectFinalization`'s context, copied and passed as part of `objectFinalization` for the purposes of easier debugging?

I can think of a few possible answers, but none of them strike me as good. I can do `NSLog(@"%@",url)`, but that causes spew. I can do a `NSAssert(url,...);` or `if (url) {}`, but both of these don't really express what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years later I discover the simplest answer. Inside the block, use:

```
(void)variable;
```

Example:

```
- (void)downloadObjectUsingURL: (NSURL *)url;
{
    id file = [self createFileForURL: url];
    Finalization objectFinalization = ^() {
        (void)url;
        [file close];
    }
    id request = [self buildRequestFromURL: url];
    [object download: request
              toFile: file
        finalization: objectFinalization];
}
```

If you only want in in debug:

```
- (void)downloadObjectUsingURL: (NSURL *)url;
{
    id file = [self createFileForURL: url];
    Finalization objectFinalization = ^() {
#if DEBUG
        (void)url;
#endif
        [file close];
    }
    id request = [self buildRequestFromURL: url];
    [object download: request
              toFile: file
        finalization: objectFinalization];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the call to `NSLog()` in `#ifdef debug.. #endif`

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and just accept this, since I think it's the best answer I'll get. :) I may make some sort of macro for this, though: `#define FORCE(a) NSLog(@"%@",a)` or `#define FORCE(a)`

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a nicer answer, but thanks to @NSResponder for making me think this way:

```
#if DEBUG
#define FORCE(a) NSParameterAssert(YES || a)
#else
#define FORCE(a)
#endif
```

This makes the code look like this:

```
- (void)downloadObjectUsingURL: (NSURL *)url;
{
    id file = [self createFileForURL: url];
    Finalization objectFinalization = ^() {
        FORCE(urL);
        [file close];
    }
    id request = [self buildRequestFromURL: url];
    [object download: request
              toFile: file
        finalization: objectFinalization];
}
```